# Is following true?

Tags: group-theory

Is following true?

Let $G=H \ltimes K$, where $H$ is a core free subgroup and $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Is the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ contained in $K$?

Comment: what does happen when $H=\{1\}$

Comment: Try taking $H$ to be a cyclic group inducing a nontrivial inner automorphism of $K$.